# How to add master-info for tags in Azure DevOps WorkItems (Backlog), so the added tags appear in the dropdown list when 'Add Tag' button is clicked

Tags: azure-devops

WorkItems (Backlog)

I want to add new master information for tags, so that my newly added tags will appear in the dropdown list when the +Add Tag button is clicked.

I want my new set of tags appear for selection in the dropdown when the Add tag is clicked. In which screen can i add this master info ?

I know that i can type-in a new tag for a WorkItem, but thats not what i want.

I cant find the screen where i can add this information. I have contributor permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there's no build-in feature to add master info for work item tags.

You could check this official link for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/add-tags-to-work-items?view=azure-devops#delete-remove-or-manage-tags

As you said, you could achieve this by add a new tag to a work item first, then this newly create tag will display as "suggestions" in the dropdown list when adding tags to other work items.

The Market Tags Manager will allow you to manage existing Tags (but not add): https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YodLabs.TagsManager2

[image]

**Update 1**

Yes, the work item tags are working the same with "Boards -> Work items" and "Boards -> Backlogs".  (It is an expected computations of Azure DevOps)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it the same for BackLog items ? Can tags (master list) not be added to BackLog items ?

Comment: Hello Anand, I have updated my answer as "Update 1", you could have a check.